# How to convert array into string and separate values by pipe

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How could i convert array into string and separate values by pipe in javascript (es6)? For example, `["one", "two", "three"]` should be converted into `"one|two|three"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Not sure that ES6 is necessary, but if you _really_ wanted to use an ES6 feature to do this, you could treat `.join()` as a template tag, e.g. ``elements.join`|` ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elements = ["one", "two", "three"];

console.log(elements.join('|'));
// expected output: one|two|three
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
let myString = myArray.join("|");
console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elements = ["one", "two", "three"];
var pipe_delimited_string = elements.join("|");
console.log(pipe_delimited_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Join function is used to convert array to string and split('') function is used to convert string into array i.e

```js
var arrayData = ['data 1', 'data 2', 'data 3'];


console.log(arrayData.join('|'));//bydefault it split with ','

var astringyData = 'data 1|data 2|data 3';

console.log(astringyData.split('|'));
```